# js toFixed issue?

Tags: javascript, tofixed

```
Number(123.456).toFixed(20)
```

emits

```
"123.45600000000000306954"
```

Where does `306954` come from? I know that numbers that are represented in binary, cant be accurate. But I didn't find any mention in the documentation that calling number(/.../) would result in a loss of precision.

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) says

> A string representation of number that does not use exponential
>   notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place. The
>   number is rounded if necessary, and the fractional part is padded with
>   zeros if necessary so that it has the specified length. If number is
>   greater than 1e+21, this method simply calls Number.toString() and
>   returns a string in exponential notation

### edit

toFixed returns Fixed point and not floating point ...
[image]

Comment: @Michael i **know this precision issues** but who said its floating and not fixed point ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely to do with floating point representation of decimal numbers.

Computers cannot represent `123.456` exactly, so the nearest binary number is used instead.

See the [floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/), or for more details [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

As per the first link, there is no built-in solution (i,.e. a decimal type) in Javascript.  There is a port of Java's `BigDecimal` class available, if this is a real issue for you rather than a matter of curiousity.

*Reponse to edit*: This isn't a problem with `Number`.  In your working example, you declare an integer literal (`123`) - these can be represented exactly.  In your failing example, you use a floating point literal `123.456`, which at the moment it's processed by the runtime will be represented by a sequence of binary digits that are not *exactly* `123.456`.

The problem is with floating point literals, not `Number` itself.

Comment: i **know** this topic. but who said its represantation is floating point ?

Comment: @Royi - **you** did when you declared `Number(123.456)`.  As soon as you typed the literal `123.456`, the precision was gone.  Even fixed-place implementations would require you to pass in a String, such as `"123.456"`, to avoid this rounding as soon as a float/double literal is declared.

Comment: im looking in the documentation - the part that says its precision is gone !

Comment: youre links are fine - but irrelevant. i know that binary represented numbers  - cant be accurate... im looking for  : where does it say that Number(...) make loosing precision.

Comment: @Royi it's not the `Number` constructor that's doing it.  Saying `var a = 123.456;` would exhibit the same problems.